# Matterport's mask rcnn doesn't train after setting up parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, faster-rcnn, matterport

Task: Mask RCNN train_shapes.ipynb tutorial. Training to segment different shapes in the artificially generated shapes dataset.

Problem: Matterport's Mask RCNN implementation doesnt work out of the box for this notebook.

Thing's I have tried:

1. Solved all the classes and package errors due to import files namely config, model, utils.
2. Solved the TF2.x errors caused due to code deprecations.

Parameters I have set:

```
Configurations:
BACKBONE                       resnet101
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     1
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.7
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
GPU_COUNT                      1
GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 1
IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  128
IMAGE_META_SIZE                16
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  128
IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [128 128   3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.001
LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0}
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           shapes
NUM_CLASSES                    4
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (8, 16, 32, 64, 128)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                5
TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
TRAIN_BN                       False
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           5
USE_MINI_MASK                  False
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STEPS               5
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001
```

Implementation details:

1. I am using coco weights to initialize my model.
2. Model in training mode.
3. Training heads first.
4. Epoch = 1
5. Learning rate = 0.001

Output:

```
Starting at epoch 0. LR=0.001

Checkpoint Path: /logs/shapes20211123T0437/mask_rcnn_shapes_{epoch:04d}.h5
Selecting layers to train
fpn_c5p5               (Conv2D)
fpn_c4p4               (Conv2D)
fpn_c3p3               (Conv2D)
fpn_c2p2               (Conv2D)
fpn_p5                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p2                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p3                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p4                 (Conv2D)
rpn_model              (Functional)
mrcnn_mask_conv1       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn1         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv2       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn2         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv1      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn1        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv3       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn3         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv2      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn2        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv4       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn4         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_bbox_fc          (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_deconv      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_logits     (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask             (TimeDistributed)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py:102: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super(SGD, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
```

- This is the only thing i can see. And there is no progress bar of epoch run. And this stays the same for 2-3 Hours.
- I later found out that [this](https://github.com/leekunhee/Mask_RCNN) individual has done the code clean up as well. So i also experimented with his ".py" files and still the same occurs.

System harware specifications:

1. Intel Xeon 12 CPU
2. 25GB RAM
3. 64GB Storage.
4. Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. VM running on company's internal server.

Software Specifications:

1. Anaconda Latest version
2. TF 2.7.0
3. Keras 2.4

Questions:

1. Why does the training doesn't start even after 3 hours?
2. Is there an error in my configuration?
3. Is my system sufficient?
4. Is the implementation correct?
5. What changes should be done to make this work?

Notebook: Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19jYZQ4SZUNdSveebgMcX4bBJ4uHXeAL9?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The training hangs, and this is actually kind of a known issue. The fix is simple:
Find the fit function in the model.py file (should be somewhere around line 2360-2370 in the TF2 project), and set the 'workers' argument to 1 and the 'use_multiprocessing' argument to False.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1- Inside the (mrcnn) folder open the file (model.py).

2- Change line 2362
from:

```
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

to:

```
workers = 1
```

3- Change line 2374
from:

```
use_multiprocessing=True,
```

to:

```
use_multiprocessing=False,
```

Or you can try using this fork where I already did these changes.
https://github.com/manasrda/Mask_RCNN
This fixed a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The fix of setting workers to 1 and disabling multi-processing didn't work. I found out that it was trying to use the CPU instead of GPU. The fix was to make sure CUDA was installed properly, or if on HPC doing something like `module load cuda` on HPC and make sure you've provisioned a node with a GPU.